# Codeigniter check existance of file returns null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've to upload a video in my project page.Code in View,

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading"><?php echo lang("ctn_502") ?></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video_file">
                </div>
</div>
```

Code in Controller,

```
$videoid=0;
if(isset($_FILES['video_file']['size']) && $_FILES['video_file']['size'] > 0) {
        $this->load->library("upload");
        // Upload image
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
           "upload_path" =>  $this->settings->info->upload_path,
           "overwrite" => FALSE,
           "max_filename" => 300,
           "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
           "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
           "allowed_types" => "avi|mp4|webm|ogv|ogg|3gp|flv",
           "max_size" => $this->settings->info->file_size,
            )
        );

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('video_file'))
        {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->template->jsonError(lang("error_97") . "<br /><br />" .
                     $this->upload->display_errors() . "<br />" . mime_content_type($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name']));
        }

        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $videoid = $this->feed_model->add_video(array(
            "file_name" => $data['file_name'],
            "file_type" => $data['file_type'],
            "extension" => $data['file_ext'],
            "file_size" => $data['file_size'],
            "userid" => $this->user->info->ID,
            "timestamp" => time()
            )
        );
    }

if(empty($videoid == 0)) {
        $this->template->jsonError(lang("error_98"));
    }
```

But the condition `if(isset($_FILES['video_file']['size']) && $_FILES['video_file']['size'] > 0) {` always return null.I Couldn't get what is wrong in my code.Can anybody help to resolve this issue?

Comment: You want to just check if you have a file before trying to upload it right? Why don't you just let the uploader take care of that... remove the if statement and if there is no file CI returns an error via `display_errors()`. Otherwise my guess is that there is an upload error before hitting the if statement and the size isn't propagated, maybe check for errors first before size: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I've the videofile contains 7.12MB,and I've also tried `(isset($_FILES['video_file']['size']) && $_FILES['video_file']['size'] > 0)` Results the same error "{"error":1,"error_msg":"Your post cannot be "empty!"}

Comment: Like I said, remove the if statement where you do all that and let CI handle it, the library already checks if there is an uploaded file, if not sends error. Even if you don't want to go that route, might be interesting just to see what kindof error it says, if any.

Comment: Just in case...Is your form enctype attribute properly set?

Comment: 'form_open_multipart(site_url("feed/add_post"), array("id" => "social-form"))' How to define enctype  here

Comment: how to handle the in CI. Where to define `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');Can you explain it?
`

Answer (score 0):

Use `!empty`

```
if(!empty($_FILES['video_file']['name'])){ }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But it also results the error `{"error":1,"error_msg":"Your post cannot be empty!"}`